# OHLC Data for US Govt. Treasury Yields?

Tags: fixed-income, data

Is there open-high-low-close data available at the daily timescale for yields? The data I can find from the Federal Reserve reports only one price, and moreover, I'm not sure when the data is reported. I know most bonds are not traded on exchanges, so it makes sense that this data is readily available, but I was wondering if this data was available anywhere.

Comment: Selected TIPS yields are available on FRED: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DTP10J28

Comment: The 10 year's yield is available here https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/V2Y00/price-history/historical though the past data looks a bit fishy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/markets/bonds/a-z/U) daily OHLC bars for bonds **yields** are sourced from [Tullett Prebon](https://www.tullettprebon.com).

Here's a sample output for [U.S. 10 Year Treasury Note](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/bond/tmubmusd10y/downloaddatapartial?startdate=01/01/2021%2021:00:00&enddate=12/31/2021%2023:59:59&daterange=d30&frequency=p1d&csvdownload=true&downloadpartial=false&newdates=false&countrycode=bx) yields in CSV format.

```json
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
03/11/2021,"1.518%","1.554%","1.479%","1.538%"
03/10/2021,"1.532%","1.571%","1.506%","1.518%"
03/09/2021,"1.599%","1.599%","1.526%","1.596%"
03/08/2021,"1.568%","1.617%","1.568%","1.599%"
03/05/2021,"1.564%","1.614%","1.538%","1.568%"
```

The Closing interpolated yields are also available directly from the [Treasury](http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%203%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202021), in XML format, starting with 1997.

```xml
<m:properties>
  <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7802</d:Id>
  <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2021-03-08T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
  <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.04</d:BC_1MONTH>
  <d:BC_2MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.04</d:BC_2MONTH>
  <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.05</d:BC_3MONTH>
  <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.06</d:BC_6MONTH>
  <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.09</d:BC_1YEAR>
  <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.17</d:BC_2YEAR>
  <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.34</d:BC_3YEAR>
  <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.86</d:BC_5YEAR>
  <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.28</d:BC_7YEAR>
  <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.59</d:BC_10YEAR>
  <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.2</d:BC_20YEAR>
  <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.31</d:BC_30YEAR>
  <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.31</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
</m:properties>
```

Another pricing source is the [Treasury Securities Ops](https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/domestic-market-operations/monetary-policy-implementation/treasury-securities/treasury-securities-operational-details) : Results : Excel : `Weighted Avg. Accpt. Price/Rate` (WAP) and `Least Favorable Accpt. Price/Rate` (LFP) columns. These two columns can be used as a measure of volatility in the bond market. For example, the volume-weighted spread between WAP and LFP showed signs of liquidity issues in the Treasury market during March 2020:

[image]

The peak day on the chart, March 19, was the day when Fed WAP for UST 2.875% 05/15/2049 during the day auction was `125.808` whereas LFP was `128.25390625`!

The Excel **Results** files maybe delayed by several weeks, but the [TSY API](https://markets.newyorkfed.org/api/tsy/purchases/results/details/last/10.csv) and the derived [chart example](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/f4ac1200/2/) above are more current. The volume weighted LFP/WAP spread is calculated as follows in SQL:

```sql
SELECT datetime, acc.entity AS "entity", acc.tags.operation_id AS "tags.operation_id", acc.tags.Operation_Type AS "tags.Operation_Type", acc.tags."Maturity/Call_Date_Range" AS "tags.Maturity/Call_Date_Range", acc.tags.operation_direction AS "tags.operation_direction",
  MAX(sub.value) AS tsy_submitted, sum(acc.value/1000000) AS tsy_accepted,
ABS(100*(SUM( acc.value*
  CASE 
    -- Rounding per Note 1 https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/desk-operations/treasury-securities
    WHEN acc.tags.operation_type IN ('Outright Bill Purchase', 'Outright FRN Purchase') THEN
      -- wap=1.516, lfp=1.5125, rlfp=1.513 pwap= 100/(1+wap/100) prlfp = 100/(1+rlfp/100) spread=100*(prlfp/pwap-1)
      (1+ROUND(lfp.value,3)/100)/(1+wap.value/100)
    ELSE
      -- wap=120.717 , lfp=120.7578125, rlfp=120.758 spread=100*(120.758/120.717-1)=0.0339637333598%
      ROUND(lfp.value,3)/wap.value
    END
  ) / SUM(acc.value)-1)) AS tsy_lfp_wap_spread
FROM "total_par_amt_submitted_($millions)" sub
   JOIN "par_amt_accepted_($)" acc
   JOIN "least_favorable_accpt._price/rate" lfp
   JOIN "weighted_avg._accpt._price/rate" wap
WHERE acc.entity = 'us.fed.nyc' 
  AND acc.datetime BETWEEN today-14*day AND next_day
GROUP BY acc.entity, acc.tags.operation_id, acc.tags.Operation_Type, acc.tags."Maturity/Call_Date_Range", acc.tags.operation_direction, datetime
WITH TIMEZONE = 'US/Eastern'  
ORDER BY datetime DESC, acc.tags.operation_id
```

Comment: This looks great! thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Bloomberg, Reuters (now Refinitiv), IDBs (ICAP used to sell rates/IRD data), trading platforms (e.g. BrokerTec, now part of CME)...this is only a partial list, I'm sure there are other sources.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. [www.quandl.com](http://www.quandl.com)